# Riemannian integrable with uniform partition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $I\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a $n-$rectangle and $f:\ I\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is Riemannian integrable. Let $\mathcal P$ is a uniform partition of $I$, that is a partition which each edge is devided into $m$ subinterval with the same length. In each subrectangle $R_i\ \ (i=1,\dots,m^n)$, we choose a representative point $x_{R_i}$.

I want to show that
$$\intop_I f=|I|\left[\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{m^n}\sum_{i=1}^{m^n}f\big(x_{R_i}\big) \right]  $$.

So, firstly, since $\mathcal P$ devides $I$ into $m^n$ subrectangle with the same volume, then
$$|I|=\sum_{i=1}^{m^n}|R_i|=m^n|R_i|. $$
Next,
\begin{align}
L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^{m^n}\big(\inf_{R_i} f\big)|R_i|\leq\sum_{i=1}^{m^n}f\big(x_{R_i}\big)|R_i|\leq\sum_{i=1}^{m^n}\big(\sup_{R_i} f\big)|R_i|.
\end{align}
Thus
$$L(f,P)\leq|I|\sum_1^{m^n}\frac{1}{m^n}f\big(x_{R_i}\big)\leq U(f,P).  $$

But now, I'm struggling to take the limit for this inequality. Could anyone give me some hints ? I really appreciate. Thank you